# JS compare two arrays with objects and remove duplicated by property name ES6 way

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Wanted to compare two arrays with objects and remove duplicate by its property name, I have these two:

```
arr1 = [{
  item:"apple",
  description: "lorem"
},{
  item:"peach",
  description: "impsum"
}]

arr2 = [{
  item:"apple", description: "dolor"
},{
  item:"grape", description: "enum"
}]
```

and I wanted this result:

```
arr3 = [{
  item:"peach", description: "impsum"
},{
  item:"grape", description: "enum"
}]
```

I've tried this es6 approach but not working `arr3 = arr1.filter(val => !arr2.includes(val));`

Comment: your question is misleading, property names on all the array are identical, property names and the value of a property are two different things, what do you want ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Array.includes` won't work because in javascript `{} !== {}`. You'll need another way like `Array.every` to check that every object in the other array doesn't have the same value of the property `item` as the current object. Also, you need to do both `arr1.filter(...)` and `arr2.filter(...)` and `concat` the results:

```
arr3 = [].concat(
    arr1.filter(obj1 => arr2.every(obj2 => obj1.item !== obj2.item)),
    arr2.filter(obj2 => arr1.every(obj1 => obj2.item !== obj1.item))
);
```

**Example:**

```js
let arr1 = [{
  item:"apple",
  description: "lorem"
},{
  item:"peach",
  description: "impsum"
}];

let arr2 = [{
  item:"apple", description: "dolor"
},{
  item:"grape", description: "enum"
}];

let arr3 = [].concat(
    arr1.filter(obj1 => arr2.every(obj2 => obj1.item !== obj2.item)),
    arr2.filter(obj2 => arr1.every(obj1 => obj2.item !== obj1.item))
);

console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 2):

See [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Spread Syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for more info.

```js
// Join Without Dupes.
const joinWithoutDupes = (A, B) => {
  const a = new Set(A.map(x => x.item))
  const b = new Set(B.map(x => x.item))
  return [...A.filter(x => !b.has(x.item)), ...B.filter(x => !a.has(x.item))]
}

// Proof.
const output = joinWithoutDupes([{item:"apple",description: "lorem"},{item:"peach",description: "impsum"}], [{item:"apple", description: "dolor"},{item:"grape", description: "enum"}])
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple and faster sample:

```js
arr1 = [{
  item:"apple",
  description: "lorem"
},{
  item:"peach",
  description: "impsum"
}]

arr2 = [{
  item:"apple", description: "dolor"
},{
  item:"grape", description: "enum"
}]

result = (counters = {}, arr1.concat(arr2).map(cur => (counters[cur.item] ? counters[cur.item]++ : (counters[cur.item] = 1), cur)).filter(cur => counters[cur.item] === 1))

console.log(result)
```